# How to write output of terminal to file

Tags: python

I want to save result of script to file. Example of script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
i=0
while i<10:
  a=raw_input('Write a number')
  print 'Result%s'%str(2*a)
  i+=1
```

And I want to save to file print value. I know that I can do that in script `f=open()...`, but I want to do that using output in terminal. I read that I can use module `subprocess` but I don't know it is correct.

Comment: `python file.py > out.txt` ??

Comment: what u want to save? results or all conversion?

Comment: Thankfully, this existed. I wanted to make a Python IDE, and than you very much for the courage to be able to ask this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

IMO this is the correct pythonic way, with-out relying on the system shell:

```
import sys
f = open("test.out", 'w')
sys.stdout = f
print "test"
f.close()
```

In python you can change what is the default `stdout` object. You just need to assign whatever you want to `sys.stdout`. I think the object just need to have a `write` method defined (not absolutely sure, though).

This would do:

```
import sys
f = open("test.out", 'w')
sys.stdout = f

i=0
while i<10:
  a=raw_input('Write a number')
  print 'Result%s'%str(2*a)
  i+=1

f.close()
```

It's essentially the same what [0605002](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1102056/0605002) suggests for systems that support syntax he uses, but realized in pure python and should be more portable.

Even more pythonic way, as per comment suggestion:

```
import sys

with open("test.out", 'w') as f:
  sys.stdout = f

  i=0
  while i<10:
    a=raw_input('Write a number')
    print 'Result%s'%str(2*a)
    i+=1
```

Of course you can refactor your "client code" and make it a function or something.

Comment: `with` statement not found!! :-)

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Yea I am not very good at python yet =(. But I did `f.close()`! =) I edited the question and added even more pythonic way. I hope everyone's content with the answer now.

Comment: OK, it is works. Thanks. I have got one more question: Is it possibility to save the result of terminal according to below sample of code

    `import sys`
    `f = open("test.out", 'w')`
    `sys.stdout = f`

    `"on terminal execute some operation (due to run another script) and I save result from terminal to the file" `
    `f.close()`

Comment: @qwerty12345 IMO, it's best to use subprocess for it. You can specify what will be used for `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`. You can look for "How can I run another script from python." there are several ways, and someone most probably already asked it. It is also possible to use `import` for this, I think.

Answer (score 25):

You can redirect the output to a file using `>` in terminal:

```
python your_script.py > output.txt
```

Comment: I don't like that you relay on shell =).

Comment: IMO OP knows writing to file can be done with `open()`, but he wants to use `print` and not `write`. But I have to admit, it is quite unclear. Maybe he does not want to change his code at all, then best shot is to use terminal, or subprocess.

Answer (score 21):

```
python file.py &> out.txt
```

This will direct all the output including the errors to the out.txt.

Comment: This is perfect. Many answers missed this

Comment: What is the difference between using &> and just > ?

Comment: &> also includes the errors but > doesn't.

Comment: Do you know how I can write to the file instead of append to it? If i run this again the output of the previous file is not written over but append to

Comment: How about deleting the out.txt before calling this?   
`rm out.txt; python file.py &> out.txt`